# Why do I have to use sudo although I'm already a member of wheel?

Tags: permission, sudo, vi

I like to edit files in my `/Library/WebServer/Documents` without having to run sudo all the time.

So I simply added my username `abbood` to the `wheel` group using [this](https://superuser.com/a/214311/234141) command:

`sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a abbood -t user wheel`

i verified that `abbood` is a member of `wheel` like so:

```
$ members wheel
abbood
root
```

If I run `ls -l` on my files in that directory.. the user is root and the group is wheel.

However as `abbood` I'm still required to sudo everytime I want to edit a file.. how come? how do I avoid that?

Comment: What do you mean by "you are required"? And what are the permissions?

Comment: ie i cannot edit files inside that directory unless if i do `sudo vi index.html`, it won't allow me if I just do `vi index.html`

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know when you show no permissions? And what do you mean by "won't allow"? Siri says "you are required to sudo"?

Answer (score 2):

Answering based on system defaults (because of lack of the information in the question):

```
[~]# ls -ld /Library/WebServer/Documents
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  170 Feb 21  2016 /Library/WebServer/Documents/

[~]# ls -l /Library/WebServer/Documents
total 72
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   3726 Feb 21  2016 PoweredByMacOSX.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  31958 Feb 21  2016 PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     45 Jun 12  2007 index.html.en
```

Members of group `wheel` do not have write permissions to the `/Library/WebServer/Documents` directory nor the files inside.

Hence adding any account to the group `wheel` will not allow this account to write files in/to the above directory.